# webpack: question mark after [ext] in config file

Tags: javascript, webpack

webpack.config.js, under rules:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
    }
  }
```

what does `?[hash]` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name parameter under the options object indicates what your file name will be evaluated to. In the [hash] case more specifically, where to place the generated content hash for the file.

So, the following config:

```
{
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    name: '[path][name].[ext]?[hash]'
  }  
}
```

Would generate something like:

```
path/to/file.png?e43b20c069c4a01867c31e98cbce33c9
```

The purpose for that is ability to easily invalidate these files when new versions are available. By having an unique hash to each file version,
the browser will discard the old one when there's a new version

You can specify hash types (md5, sha256, etc) and other configurations, read more:
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/

Answer (score 0):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it has to do with adding a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to bypass browser caching so that when you recompile, the newest version of your resources (source code or other resources) is loaded instead of an old cached version. And the [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is just so that the query string is based on the content of your raw resource.

Answer (score 0):

hash is basically calculated for a build.

hash returns the build hash. If any portion of the build changes, this changes as well. [check here](https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/adding-hashes-to-filenames/) and [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/153) for more details